# Parse json array in jquery in foreach loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I'm trying to parse json array with objects and use them to create multiple checkboxes. This is what I have:

JSON data:

```
[{
    "ID": 1,
    "Name": "Bacon",
    "Description": "",
    "Price": 0
}, {
    "ID": 2,
    "Name": "Beef",
    "Description": "",
    "Price": 0
}, {
    "ID": 3,
    "Name": "Chicken",
    "Description": "",
    "Price": 0
}, {
    "ID": 4,
    "Name": "Ham",
    "Description": "",
    "Price": 0
}]
```

In the JS code I have this:

```
success: function (data) {
    var objects = JSON.stringify(data);
    for (var key in objects) {
        var checkBox = "<input type='checkbox' data-price='" + key.Price + "' name='" + key.Name + "' value='" + key.ID + "'/>" + key.Name + "<br/>";
        $(checkBox).appendTo('#modifiersDiv');
    };
    $('#addModifiers').modal('show');
}
```

But the key object doesn't contain any data. My question is how I can do foreach loop and get the data I need and fetch that data in the checkbox properties.

Comment: Why would you stringify before looping? If anything, you want to `parse`

Comment: Your data is an array.  You should just iterate the array and then refer to `data[i].ID`, `data[i].Name`, etc...  Also, why are you calling `JSON.stringify()`?  You want it to be a javascript array, not a string.

Comment: You need to know what `data` is in the success handler.  If you use jQuery's ajax call properly, it should already be a javascript array and you can just directly iterate it as an array.  Step 1, do a `console.log(data)` to see exactly what it is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your data should already be a javascript array because you've specified the JSON type for the jQuery Ajax call so it should have already parsed the JSON into javascript.  As such, you can just directly iterate it as the array:

```
success: function (data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var checkBox = "<input type='checkbox' data-price='" + data[i].Price + "' name='" + data[i].Name + "' value='" + data[i].ID + "'/>" + data[i].Name + "<br/>";
        $(checkBox).appendTo('#modifiersDiv');
    }
    $('#addModifiers').modal('show');
}
```

Or, if you want to use jQuery's `.each()` iterator instead of a `for` loop, you can do this:

```
success: function (data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, item) {
        var checkBox = "<input type='checkbox' data-price='" + item.Price + "' name='" + item.Name + "' value='" + item.ID + "'/>" + item.Name + "<br/>";
        $(checkBox).appendTo('#modifiersDiv');
    });
    $('#addModifiers').modal('show');
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't be using `var objects = JSON.stringify(data);` since the data is already a JSON object.

Use `JSON.stringify` to create a string from a object

Use `JSON.parse` is to create an object from a string

Example:

```
var data = [{id: 1, name:'personsName'}, {id: 2, name:'personsName2'}]
var string = JSON.stringify(data)
var json = JSON.parse(string)
```

You can loop trough the data and append by using:

```
data.forEach(function(key, index){
   $("#modifiersDiv")
      .append($("<input></input>")
      .attr("type", "checkbox")
      .attr("data-price",key.Price )
      .attr("name",key.Name )
      .attr("value",key.ID)
      .text(key.Name); 
}
```

Comment: If you use jQuery's Ajax call properly, it will already have parsed the JSON.

Comment: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character I'm getting this error, let me see what I can do

Comment: @jfriend00, only if he have set the type attribue on ajax function ;)

Comment: Try without the JSON.parse, as @jsfriend00 mentioned, you should already have a JSON object.

Comment: dataType: "json" I have that included

Comment: how I can do the for each part to iterate through the items?

Comment: Updated for the iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You try to change your json string on json string and not on json object (use JSON.parse to do that).

```
// You have a string and you want and object : 
var string = "[....]";
var object = JSON.parse(string);

// You have a object and you want and string: 
var object = {...};
var string = JSON.stringify(object);
```

Or better you can use the type attribut of jQuery ajax function, (put 'json' after your success function and jQuery give you avec object and not a Json string). 
If you have already do that, you already have an object, so you don't need to update your data

Comment: how I can do the for each part to iterate through the items?

Comment: If you have set the type attribute on jQuery ajax function, data is already an object, so juste don't call you JSON function and rename data params to objects.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
  $.each(data, function(key, value){
      var checkBox = "<input type='checkbox' data-price='" + value.Price + "' name='" + value.Name + "' value='" + value.ID + "'/>" + value.Name + "<br/>";
      $(checkBox).appendTo('#modifiersDiv');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () { 
let table_responsive_data_html = "<table class='main-cart-table' id='tblOne'>";
        table_responsive_data_html += '</table>';
        alert(table_responsive_data_html);
});
```